# Using a 1:M relationship to create 1:1

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I was recently asked to change my application design and have a solution but it feels dirty and I was hoping there are alternatives out there I'm not thinking of.

I have a DB table Activity that has an associate Product table that has several fields like name, description, price, etc.

Normally I would have a drop down in my interface populated with the various products, and upon submission, put a product id in my activity table. Every time I need to pull up an activity, i just do a join on the key and pull in the relevant product info.

Now the request is that if you pull up the activity but someone has altered say the description of the product since the activity was entered, that it show the original description, not the new one.

The main solution I can think of is simply duplicate all the product fields in the activity table and fill them in based on the selected drop down, but that feels like it could get very messy. Both for increased storage, but also for potential queries and extra work if new columns are needed in the future. This also feels like having a relational database pointless.

Is this solution the one I should go with or perhaps a hybrid one with copied fields, but retain the foreign key for reports/queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a description change; it sounds like a new product is being created.  If the product data content needs to remain with the product ID as of the entry time, then the product data cannot really change.  A new product needs to be added.  The description is behaving like a key.

When the description changes and a new product is added, the old product needs to be deactivated.  It's still in the domain table because the 'old' product records are tied to it but new activity items can't use it.  The original or previous product ID can be stored in the domain table entry for the new product.

```
Product ID    Description   is_Active  Previous_Product_ID  Add_Date
    1         myOldDesc         N                            1/1/2017
    2         NewDesc           Y             1              1/1/2018
```

You'll end up with a chain of product changes.  I worked on a system many years ago that forced the relational design in this way.  It was very difficult to work with.

The activity table seems to contain historical data.  I recommend denormalizing it.  You'll still have the product domain table for your drop-down which can be modified according to relational practices.  On a change, create an audit record to record the history of the changes.  When an activity item is created, instead of storing the product_id, store the actual product information.  The advantage of the relational model is that you can change the description without needing to change every related activity record.  But in this case, you don't want to change the related records so why normalize it?

Comment: I believe I was concentrating on how I would be getting reports later on like if a staff member who had a name change I would want all the history for that person but you are correct, to maintain the 'history' that is being requested the name change really would be a new staff member.

Comment: @enfrost  Are we talking about transactions or history?  For a staff name change, I would not create a new record.  I'd change the name on the original record and create an audit trail to indicate the name change.  BUT on database items that are historical like pay stubs, I'd store the actual name not the identifier.  So if my name changes on October 1, my September pay stubs would still have my old name even though my name has changed on my record.